# How to unserialize PHP session in node.js?

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, session, serialization

I am storing the PHP `$_SESSION` data in a database.

Then from a Node.js server I want to take that data and unserialize it.

I tried to use [js-php-unserialize](https://github.com/naholyr/js-php-unserialize) like this:

```js
con.query('SELECT user_id, data ' + 
            'FROM sessions ' +
            'WHERE session_id = ? AND session_id IS NOT NULL AND user_id IS NOT NULL'
          , [tokenId] , function(queryError, rows){

    if(queryError){
      throw queryError;
    }

    console.log(rows[0].data);
    return;
    var data;

    if(rows[0]){
      data = PHPUnserialize.unserialize(rows[0].data);
      var now = Math.floor(new Date() / 1000);

      if(data.MA_IDLE_TIMEOUT < now){
        throw 'The session Times out!';
      }

      if(myIP != data.MA_IP_ADDRESS){
        throw 'This session have been hijacked!';
      }
```

But this keeps throwing this error:

```
SyntaxError: Unknown / Unhandled data type(s): m
    at error (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\php-unserialize\php-unseriali
ze.js:54:13)
    at _unserialize (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\php-unserialize\php-un
serialize.js:166:11)
    at Object.unserialize (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\php-unserialize\
php-unserialize.js:173:10)
    at C:\Program Files\nodejs\app.js:41:25
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\ex
press\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:13
1:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\express\lib\router\r
oute.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\ex
press\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:277:22
    at Function.process_params (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\express\lib
\router\index.js:330:12)
```

Here is the data that I am trying to unserialize:

```
MA_IP_ADDRESS|s:10:"10.0.4.195";MA_USER_AGENT|s:72:"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1;
 WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.0";MA_IDLE_TIMEOUT|i:1442101764;
```

How can I correct this issue?

Comment: Did you try the phpjs version of unserialize? http://phpjs.org/functions/unserialize/

Comment: I think you might be doing it wrong, why don't you use JSON instead of a serialization ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `.unserializeSession()` instead of `.unserialize()`.